# SSRS Toggling adding columns, when exporting report to excel

Tags: reporting-services

[image][image][image]I created a drill-down report in SSRS.
Now, when I am exporting this report into MS Excel, getting additional column which is sum of child rows' value. However, before exporting the report is displayed correctly.

I do not need this columns to be created. What can I do with this issue?

Comment: Would you please share a screenshot of your report design? It's not clear how a column would show a sum of row values.

Comment: @StevenWhite, thank you! Some screenshots are available regarding my question. I hope, now is much more clear.